# Why doesnt bounty come back to the owner when it expires?

Tags: support, bounties

I had a bounty on one of my own [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789983/ie8-post-file-targeting-iframe-arrives-on-server-as-null), which I then answered. It was the only answer and it received up votes from other users. It would be nice that if you put a bounty on a question and it doesn't get answered by anyone else that the bounty gets returned to you, after all you are spending those points to attract good answers, if you don't get any then surely it should come back to you? maybe I'm just seeing it wrong.

Comment: Why doesn't money come back to the advertiser when no one contact him after he posted an advertisement?

Comment: @hims056: But then why would you pay a "bounty" hunter if he didn't complete the job?

Comment: @musefan - You have asked the same question. See my first comment. The goal of bounty is not to *get answers* but to *get extra attentions*.

Comment: @hims056: Actually, I am suggesting a counter-argument to your point of view. I believe the name "bounty" is misleading as I would say it indicates you want to pay someone to provide you with a solution, if you don't get that solution then why should you pay?

Comment: @musefan that would be a feature request to change the name, which is seperate from why it is the way it is

Comment: possible duplicate of [My bounty didn't get me an acceptable new answer on an already answered question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69748/my-bounty-didnt-get-me-an-acceptable-new-answer-on-an-already-answered-question) and of [What if I offer a bounty and don't get any good answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49394/what-if-i-offer-a-bounty-and-dont-get-any-good-answers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bounty isn't technically to attract answers, it is to attract **attention**. You had your week of attention and it would be unfair for you to get that for free.

Additionally if you got it back then numerous exploits would be possible such as;

- Attracting attention to your own question/answer pair; getting upvotes and then getting the bounty back as well.
- Downvoting good answers in the hope of avoiding (auto) paying the bounty
- etc

Comment: I would like to add that I think you should get your bounty back if no answers have been provided. Adding your own, like in this instance, should not provide a refund as it is the OP's choice to add the answer. Screw the advertisement, if you put on a bounty because you want help, why should you pay if no help is provided

Comment: @musefan we don't want terrible, no effort questions getting bounties put on them. If the bounty is gone no matter what then you have to put effort in. Equally,  what if you get an answer but don't like it?

Comment: Why not? If they are easy to answer then the OP will lose their bounty rep. Otherwise if they are really bad questions then they will get closed anyway (which I assume already has a procedure in terms of where the bounty goes). Of course, both easy to answer question and bad questions will be actioned long before the ability to post a bounty anyway

Comment: thanks, for straightening out my perspective on bounties, I'll be more cautious in future

Answer (score 6):

Bounties are like advertisements. You don't get the money back when nobody acts on the ad. A bounty has the purpose of putting attention to your question, not more.

Comment: I would say it is a poorly worded feature then...

Comment: @musefan: In fact it is :)